# Derivative of Heaviside step function multiplied by an exponential

Tags: dirac-delta

Let $f(y)=e^y\mathscr{H}(y)$ where $\mathscr{H}$ is the Heaviside step function. We know that the derivative of $\mathscr{H}$ is given by
$$\frac{d}{dy}\mathscr{H}(y)=\delta(y),$$
Then how come, in both a paper (Bouchouev, Isakov - The inverse problem of option pricing) and the output of Wolfram Alpha has the following
$$\frac{d}{dy}f(y)=\frac{d}{dy}(e^y\mathscr{H}(y))=\delta(y)+e^y\mathscr{H}(y),$$
rather than what you'd expect from the product rule
$$\frac{d}{dy}f(y)=\frac{d}{dy}(e^y\mathscr{H}(y))=e^y\delta(y)+e^y\mathscr{H}(y).$$

Comment: Intuitively, the delta cannot care about what a function does globally. So we have the definition that $$f(x)\delta(x-x_0)=f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)$$

Comment: Note $\delta(y) e^y = \delta(y) e^0 = \delta(y)$